# consumer cannot print out the messages from the producer

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Okay, I got the same error **`Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000`** if I run this command: `spark-submit --jars spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.4.jar receiver_based.py localhost:9092 test2`

If I follow the solution from the post above and change `localhost:2181` instead of `localhost:9092` then it seems like now the **zookeeper** has been connected but I could not print out the message from **Producer** using this command `spark-submit --jars spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.4.jar receiver_based.py localhost:2181 test2` even though I check the message from **Consumer** by using this command `kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test2 --from-beginning` and it successfully printed out `This is a message`.

### So basically, I followed the solution in the link above then I got another problem. The **consumer** cannot print out the messages from the **producer**

Here is the command to create a message with topic test2:

`echo "This is a message" | kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test2`

Here is my `receiver_based.py` file:

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from uuid import uuid1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="twiiterproject")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2) # 2 second window

    broker, topic = sys.argv[1:]
    print("Broker: {0}, Topic{1}".format(broker,topic))
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,
                                  broker,
                                  'raw-event-streaming-consumer',{topic:1})
    lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
    print("This god damn line alibaba: {0}".format(lines.pprint()))
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split("")).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
    counts.pprint()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: In what order are you running those commands? By default, Spark reads the latest offsets

Comment: First I started `zookeeper` and then `kafka-server`. Next, I created topic and message. Then I tested the message by using this command `kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test2 --from-beginning ` and it showed the message like the input. Everything was good. But when I ran `spark-submit --jars spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.4.jar receiver_based.py localhost:9092 test2` The message did not show up.

Comment: Can you run the producer after you start Spark?

Comment: Yes I can, by using this comment  `kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test2 --from-beginning`

Comment: But when I use this command `spark-submit --jars spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.4.jar receiver_based.py localhost:2181 test2` The message did not show up.

Comment: Yes, I know. Because Spark starts at the end of the topic, by default... You're not comparing the same behavior if you include `--from-beginning`

Comment: Then what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You're not comparing the same behavior. Read the documentation, *carefully*, you see this section.

> In the Kafka parameters, you must specify either `metadata.broker.list` or `bootstrap.servers`. **By default, it will start consuming from the latest offset of each Kafka partition**. If you set configuration `auto.offset.reset` in Kafka parameters to smallest, then it will start consuming from the smallest offset.

You need to do this, and don't use Zookeeper as a parameter anymore.

```
kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,
                              topics = [topic],
                              kafkaParams = {"bootstrap.servers": broker, "auto.offset.reset": "smallest"}))
```

Otherwise, you need to run the console-producer **after** the Spark application starts

---

Note: kafka-0-8 package is deprecated as of Spark 2.3.0, and you may want to try Structured Streaming instead.

Comment: Thanks, but i got this error when trying to use your code `TypeError: createStream() missing 1 required positional argument: 'topics'`

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/python/pyspark.streaming.html#pyspark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils.createDirectStream

Comment: Now I got `TypeError: createStream() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'zkQuorum' and 'groupId'` after using your updated answer.

Comment: According to that link, those aren't required, but still, test your previous code with sending a message afterwards.